# Multi login problem using Twitter and Facebook Oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

I am adding Twitter and Facebook login to a MVC 3 test application using TweetSharp and Facebook C# SDK.

Currently when a user signs in using Twitter I create a user account for that user in a user table and store the id, token, and token secret in a separate table with a foreign key to the user table. Since the id, token and token secret do not expire I can quickly locate the right user account when the user logs in next time using Twitter.

What if the very same user logs in using Facebook next time? Since Twitter does not provide email in their API and I therefore have no common piece of information to tie a user account to either Twitter or Facebook I assume I have to create a new user account for a Facebook login? Does anyone have any experience with this? Are there any ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, more of a work around. I was faced with the same problem and ended up forcing the user to complete thier account profile by asking for their email address before allowing them to proceed any further. This meant that if the email address coming back with the Facebook auth matched the email address created with the twitter signin then I didn't need to create another account.

The bigger difficulty was coming the other way, if the account was created by the facebook auth first. It meant an untidy marry up of accounts.

To be honest the information we got from allowing users to sign in with twitter was not worth the effort and in the end finished up only allowing Facebook auths. I'm not sure how important twitter is to your solution.

Not the perfect answer I know, but I thought I would share my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I might go with Facebook only for now.

Comment: Can you simply get their email from their facebook/twitter profile when they link their account to your app? All you need to do is request permission to access their email address when they sign up with Facebook/Twitter and send them an initial password if they want to log in by email next time

Answer (score 2):

I identify each user  internally with a unique key. I check cookies for the user key when any user hits the site.  If there's no cookie I create a new key. add it to the user database and set a new cookie.  Once a user completes registration the first time by logging in with any of Facebook,  Twitter or .Net membership , that key is forever married to that user.

So when an existing Twitter user logs in for the first time with Facebook, we know who they are because their user key exists.  It is basically the same solution as macou suggested.  Macou's has the plus of working on a new machine or if cookies are cleared, the cookie solution has the plus of not requiring additional user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use just a cookie because I can login as facebook then my wife login as twitter using the same browser, you shouldn't link the two accounts in this case.

I think you need to do more than that:

1. Use a cookie then
2. Use name/first name/login name/... to see if they match.

Example:

1. Cookie id: 18459439731114330636, find user with id = 18459439731114330636. Found, go to 2, not found, go to 3.
2. Is username/first name/last name/... matches the current user? if yes, link accounts. if not, go to 3.
3. Create a new user.